# conflicting cross-version suffixes Error in Apache Ignite

Tags: scala, ignite

I have a Spark Ignite program. When I use sbt to build the program, it reports error.

This is a very simple program, which is an empty project with just a sbt file.

> build.sbt:
>
> ```
> name := "testsss"
>
> version := "1.0"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-core" % "1.9.0"
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-indexing" % "1.9.0"
> libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-spark" % "1.9.0"
> ```

The error is

> Error:Error while importing SBT project:
> ...
>
> ```
> [info]
> Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.8 ... [error] Modules were
> resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in
> {file:/Users/lzhan71/Documents/IgniteMaster/}ignitemaster: [error]
>
> org.scalatest:scalatest _2.11, _2.10 [error]    com.twitter:chill
> _2.11, _2.10 [error]    org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe _2.11, _2.10 [error]    org.apache.spark:spark-tags _2.11, _2.10 [trace] Stack
> trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output. [trace]
> Stack trace suppressed: run 'last :ssExtractDependencies' for the
> full output. [error] (:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in:
> org.scalatest:scalatest, com.twitter:chill,
> org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-tags [error]
> (*:ssExtractDependencies) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in:
> org.scalatest:scalatest, com.twitter:chill,
> org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-tags [error]
> Total time: 17 s, completed Apr 28, 2017 4:41:00 PM
> ```
>
> See
>   complete log in /Users/lzhan71/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2016.2/sbt.last.log

I checked. It seems that `"ignite-spark" % "1.9.0" used a different version of those conflict dependence with spark-core and spark-sql. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in `ignite-spark`. It [depends](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-spark/1.9.0) simultaneously on `spark-unsafe_2.10` and `scala-library` 2.11.8, which should never happen. Report it and wait until a new version is released or workaround by getting its source code, fixing the `spark-unsafe_2.10` dependency and recompiling (quite likely no source code fixes are needed).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try fixing it like this:
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-spark" % "2.2.0" excludeAll(ExclusionRule("org.apache.spark"))